# Integral of a floor function $\iint_D [x + y] \, dx\, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given a domain
$$D=[0,2]×[0,2]$$
How can I calculate the integral $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\iint_D [x + y]  \, dx\, dy}\quad$$

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Note the floor function is written `\lfloor x+y\rfloor` $\lfloor x+y\rfloor$ with semi-brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Observe that $0\le x+y\le 4$ on $D$. Consider the following cases
$$
m\le x+y<m+1,\quad m=0,1,2,3
$$
Then split your integral into four pieces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about breaking the domain into
$$
D=D_0\cup D_1\cup D_2
$$
where $$
{
D_0=\{(x,y): 0<x+y< 0.5\}
\\
D_1=\{(x,y): 0.5<x+y< 1.5\}
\\
D_2=\{(x,y): 1.5<x+y< 2\}
}
$$?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We can divide in four areas $A,B,C,D$ inside I indicated the value of $\lfloor x+y\rfloor$

Thus $I=0A+1B+2C+3D$ but notice that $A=D$ so $$I=(A+B+C+D)+(C+D)=Q+\frac 12Q$$

where $Q=4$ is the area of the square.

Comment: Amusingly, the four areas here are in the ratio 1:3:3:1 which are familiar from the fourth row of Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

According to the question, we have$$[x+y]=k-1((x,y)\in D_k,k=1,2,3,4).$$
So$$I=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}\iint\limits_{D_k}[x+y]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{4}(k-1)|D_k|=|D_2|+2|D_3|+3|D_4|.$$
and the $|D_k|$ is the area of $D_k$.Hence
$$I=3+\frac{3}{2}.$$